# Adding up buffers into one

Tags: arrays, pointers, opengl, vertex, vertex-buffer

I have a mesh consisting of several entries.
Every entry contains it's own list of faces, vertices, normals, colors and texture coordinates.

Can I loop though all of my entries and use `glVertexAttribPointer` to cummulate data of an attribute in a single buffer object, like this?:

```
glBindBuffer(vbo);
for(Entry* e : entries) {
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, e->vertices);
    ...
}
```

In other words, will repeated calls on `glVertexAttribPointer` for attribute `0` of buffer `vbo` rewrite the data pointed on before or not?

If yes, is there any effective solution out of copying all vertices into one consecutive memory block before calling `glVertexAttribPointer` only once for the whole buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glVertexAttribPointer does only store (for each attribute) the last information you supplied to it. So appending buffers is not possible by this method.

You have two options when you have a situation like yours:

1. Issue for each buffer a separate draw-call
2. Copy the data off all buffers into a single buffer and issue one draw-call for it. Note that in this case the indices might have to be adjusted to point to the correct positions in the combined buffer.

Comment: Hmm... That is what I thought. I have got to redo the whole mesh loading. TStill, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`glVertexAttribPointer()` does not copy anything. It only sets state that specifies where the vertex data will be fetched from. If you call it repeatedly for the same attribute, each call will replace the previous state, and the last one wins.

Starting with OpenGL 3.1, there is a `glCopyBufferSubData()` call ([man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glCopyBufferSubData.xml)) that allows you to copy data from one buffer to another. Using this, you could allocate a buffer with enough space for all verctices, and then copy the smaller buffers into the buffer holding all vertices.

That being said, it does not sound like a great idea to use it this way. If you want all vertices in the same buffer, it's much easier and more efficient to store them in that buffer right from the start.

You definitely should not copy around the vertex data on each draw call. While reducing the number of draw calls is desirable, copying around vertex data is **much** more expensive.

Comment: Thank for clarification. I eventually rewrote it so it stored everything in one buffer.